# due to increased climate warming and development

Tags: word-usage

*Science* magazine just tweeted:

> An avalanche of rock and ice triggered the February 2021 Chamoli disaster in India, which left more than 200 people dead or missing. The results in Science highlight the increasing risk in the Himalayas **due to increased climate warming and development**.

Source: [Twitter @ScienceMagazine](https://twitter.com/ScienceMagazine/status/1404430945810255873)

Does "development" refer to "development (of climate change)"? Or refer to "development (of human economic or non-economic activities)"?

Comment: No, it refers to economic development.

Comment: But it would have been clearer if **development** had preceded **climate warming**. On the other hand, Twitter isn't a good guide to grammar.

Comment: These things can't really be deduced from the grammar. You have to deduce the meaning from context. "Increased climate development" doesn't make sense, so you have to assume it's either "increased a) climate warming and b) developement" or "a) increased climate warming and b) development".

Comment: What @DJClayworth said. Which I think strictly speaking makes this question Off Topic "Opinion-Based" - even though in practice all native speakers would have the ***same*** opinion here (that the cited text does ***not*** refer to something called ***climate development***), that's just a matter of pragmatics and common sense, not something implied by the form of the utterance itself.

Comment: I don't think it's off topic, it's that the answer is "grammar won't tell you and you have to use context and meaning". You might give an indication of the most likely interpretation, warning that you could be wrong.

Comment: "Development" here refers to new building structures, mining operations, physical infrastructure, etc.. Economic development couldn't directly trigger a fatal disaster in the Himalayas